# Google chrome and askubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, google-chrome, flash

I'm having a strange problem since the new installation of Ubuntu 13.10 x64. here is a screenshot[image] as you see my badge icons are not loading and vote buttons are messed (I haven't even touched them-up voted or down voted) this is only with Google-chrome (Firefox and other browsers are good) and with askubuntu site only...other stack exchange sites render as normal...why is this? does askubuntu site has some kind of interfere with Google-chrome? I reinstalled google-chrome but the problem exists...

Ubuntu 13.10 x64
Google-chrome-Version 31.0.1650.63

Comment: You have several extensions. Try with all of them disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling does not clear the browser's cache. Since nobody else has complained about having problems with the page, it's likely your cache is the problem.

In order to [delete Chrome's cache](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en), follow this procedure:

- Click the Chrome menu button on the browser toolbar.
- Select *Tools*.
- Select *Clear browsing data*.
- In the dialog that appears, select *Empty the cache*.
- Click *Clear browsing data*.

Comment: Or you could just press Ctrl + Shift + Delete.